# How to scale the image in UITableViewRowAction image to be suitable with dynamic cell height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try to customize the UITableViewRowAction buttons, so I use image instead of the default button.

my problem is the cell height is dynamic so if the cell's height was so large the image in UITableViewRowAction is repeated!, like this:

[image]

so how can I keep the image always centered whatever was the cell height?

my code is:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    //delete location 

    let deleteAction: UITableViewRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "         ", handler: {(tableViewRowAction:UITableViewRowAction, index:NSIndexPath) -> Void in


        self.deleteFavouriteLocationFromList(indexPath.row)


    })


    let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "delete_icon_cell")!
    image.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.Automatic)

    let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(image.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.29, 0.3))
    let hasAlpha = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
    image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: scaledImage)


    //edit location name

    let editAction: UITableViewRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "         ", handler: {(tableViewRowAction:UITableViewRowAction, index:NSIndexPath) -> Void in


        self.presentEditFavouriteLocationNamePopUp(indexPath.row)


    })


    let editImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "edit_icon_cell")!
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
    editImage.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

    let editScaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: editScaledImage)



    return [deleteAction,editAction]


}
```

thanks.